# How to get selected text in Google Docs with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

I'm building a Chrome Extension for Google Docs, and I am trying to get the selected text from the current document being edited:

[image]

However when I trying running this code, it's returning an empty string ' ':

```
const docsFrame = document.getElementsByClassName('docs-texteventtarget-iframe')[0]
docsFrame.contentDocument.getSelection().toString()
```

There was a library called [Google Docs Utils](https://github.com/Amaimersion/google-docs-utils) that used to be able to do this, but since Docs switched to Canvas-based rendering, the library no longer works.

EDIT:

Here's an example [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v9IbSlbiWdgxngQlEHq4zv29f_Zw-ioZqWKSJWtYo7k/edit?usp=sharing) to test it out

EDIT # 2:

Made some progress, found this thread with a lot of potential soltutions on it:
https://github.com/Amaimersion/google-docs-utils/issues/10

Comment: Give a link with a document and text to select and get.

Comment: @oleedd https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v9IbSlbiWdgxngQlEHq4zv29f_Zw-ioZqWKSJWtYo7k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, it seems to be only in `<canvas>`. It is not text but graphics. `getSelection()` works only for text nodes (what you can find with `ctrl+f` in the console). Learn canvas methods.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Let me research and try some canvas methods to see if it's possible...

Comment: Just skimmed through that github issues thread -- there's a lot of good info in there & I bet the answer is somewhere in those 90 replies. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to accomplish it with the help of the thread I mentioned above and through studying some open source code. I am not sure if I am allowed to post open source code here and to avoid licensing conflicts, I will post here the general steps I found:

1. Enable screen reader functionality / SVG reading. Google will add svg and rect elements to `".kix-canvas-tile-selection"` that contain the text that was typed in. Look towards the second half of [this thread](https://github.com/Amaimersion/google-docs-utils/issues/10) for different solutions to enabling this.
2. Use `$(".kix-page-paginated").get()` to get the current page on Google Docs. Then use $(window).height() calculations to figure out what page the user is currently on.
3. After accomplishing the two above, you can use a function like so below to get the line of text

   ```
    function getSelectedLineOfText(page) {
      const overlaps = (a, b) => a.left < b.right && a.right > b.left && a.top < b.bottom && a.bottom > b.top
      const selectionRects = $(".kix-canvas-tile-selection > svg > rect", page).get()
        .map(el => el.getBoundingClientRect())
      // Using text elements on that page and the selection rects, find the actual selected line of text.
      const textElements $("svg > g[role=paragraph] > rect", page).get();
   ```

Note: as you can see from the function name, this can only get an entire selected line in the file. It can't get the specific text selected within a line.

[image]

So here, "name is Bob. Hi my name is Bob. Hi my name is Bob." will be returned. I was struggling to get more specific than this, so if anyone has a clue, please feel free to add / create another answer.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way you can do this is by using a [Google Add-on script](https://script.google.com/home).

You'll get dropped into the Google App Scripts interface, which gives you access to Google Doc's canvas APIs, allowing you to do exactly what you're currentlty struggling to do.

Your challenge then will probably be reconciling the fact that the Google Extension store/marketplace is a different entity from the Google Add-on/Workspace marketplace.

Personally, I think you should just go all-in on writing a Google add-on. Makes life way simpler than writing a Chrome extension.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I'm building a project that should work on multiple sites, not just Google Docs, but since Docs is a major platform, I would like for my extension to work here too. Grammarly and Wordtune somehow does it, so there has to be a way

Comment: That's a fair point. I haven't written a Google extension in a while so I'll have to see what the prevailing literature is for using Google docs' canvas APIs inside an extension.

Comment: Yea I'm trying to research ways to connect the two while also looking at a non-Add-on way to do it (and have made some progress)