# How to get cursor location in Google Docs with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

I'm building a Chrome Extension for Google Docs, and I am trying to the last 6 characters before the cursor location. For example, in the screenshot below, I want the output of the function to be "tart: "

[image]

I see a previous question similar to this:
[How to get selected text in Google Docs with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019646/how-to-get-selected-text-in-google-docs-with-javascript). However, this focuses on selected text. In my extension, text is not being selected. I need to get the preview of text at a cursor location.

Answer (score 0):

I was reviewing the Document API to see if there was a way to find the cursor location in a Google Doc. However, it seems that this option is not available yet using Google Docs API.

However, it is possible using Google Apps Script using the method `getCursor()`. If you are willing to create your Chrome Extension for Google Docs using Apps Script, you can use this method. You need to take the following in consideration:

> Gets the user's cursor in the active document. A script can only
> access the cursor of the user who is running the script, and only if
> the script is bound to the document.

The Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getcursor), has the following sample code:

```
// Insert some text at the cursor position and make it bold.
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
if (cursor) {
  // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If the insertion returns null, the cursor's
  // containing element doesn't allow insertions, so show the user an error message.
  var element = cursor.insertText('ಠ‿ಠ');
  if (element) {
    element.setBold(true);
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text here.');
  }
} else {
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor.');
}
```

It seems that the method `getCursor()` creates a class called `Position`, and it has his own set of methods like `getElement()`, `getSurroundingText()`, `insertText(text)`, etc. You can read more information about those methods [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position#methods).

If you really want to get this feature in Google Docs API, you can make the request by following the steps in this [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/support#developer_product_feedback).